# How to see VPN connection statistics?

Tags: network, vpn

I live in China, which requires me to use several VPN's to access the outside web.  Occasionally, some VPN's are either totally blocked or suffer from high packet loss.

In Windows, it is easy to see statistics such as the packets in/out, the compression ratio, and most importantly for me, the packet loss ratio.  Is there a way to see VPN connection quality information OS X?

Comment: It depends on how your VPN is set up.  Are you using a third party VPN client, or a native OS X set up? Which version of Mac OS X are you running?

Comment: Native OS X VPN (PPTP/L2TP).  Mavericks.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing as nice and easy as Windows provides, however you can get the info you require if you enable verbose logging on your PPTP connection:

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Network**.
2. Select your your VPN service from the list of services on the left.
3. Click **Advanced…**.

   [image]
4. Then tick **Use verbose logging** and click **OK**, then **Apply**.

   [image]
5. In Terminal, run the following command:

   ```
   tail -f /var/log/ppp.log
   ```